# How to share apt-package across Docker containers

Tags: docker, ros

I want to use docker to help me stay organized with developing and deploying package/systems using ROS (Robot Operating System).

I want to have multiple containers/images for various pieces of software, and a single image that has all of the ROS dependencies. How can I have one container use the apt-packaged from my dependency master container?

For example, I may have the following containers:

- MyRosBase: `sudo apt-get install` all of the ros dependencies I need (There are many). Set up some other Environment variables and various configuration items.
- MyMoveApplication: Use the dependencies from MyRosBase and install any extra and specific dependencies to this image. Then run software that moves the robot arm.
- MySimulateApplication: Use the dependencies from MyRosBase and install any extra and specific dependencies to this image. Then run software that simulates the robot arm.

How do I use apt packages from container in another container without reinstalling them on each container each time?

Comment: You can make your downstream images be FROM a common base image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own images that serve you as base images using Dockerfiles.

Example:

```
mkdir ROSDocker
cd ROSDocker
vim Dockerfile-base

FROM debian:stretch-slim
RUN apt-get install dep1 dep2 depn

sudo docker build -t yourusername/ros-base:0.1 -f Dockerfile-base .
```

After the build is complete you can create another docker file from this base image.

```
FROM yourusername/ros-base:0.1
RUN apt-get install dep1 dep2 depn
```

Now build the second images:

```
sudo docker build -t yourusername/mymoveApplication:0.1 -f Dockerfile-base .
```

Now you have an image for your move application, each container that you run from this image will have all the dependencies installed.

You can have docker image repository for managing your built images and sharing between people/environments.

This example can be expanded multiple times.

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear, if two different images are FROM the common base image, the common base will not apt-get install twice? The packages will be cached and it will only happen once?

Comment: There is one common base and your other Dockerfiles start from it (as a precompiled binary, if you’d like to think of it that way).  When you start FROM something it doesn’t repeat the base image’s steps.

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted to verify. Now, if a modify the base image's DockerFile, then the image will be "recompiled" as long as I build it again?

Comment: You need to rebuild the downstream images too.

Comment: Can you make it clearer that when using `FROM yourusername/ros-base:0.1`, you don't need to install the same dependencies (`dep1 dep2 depn`) again, so it should be `RUN apt-get install depA depB depZ` (or something else different).