# Docker, can you cache apt-get package installs?

Tags: docker

The beginning of my docker file is below, I change the stuff after it often but never this part, but it takes a while to run, especially `RUN apt-get -y install npm`, can I cache the package download somehow? I looked at docker caching but I don't think that is what it does?

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install ruby
RUN apt-get -y install ruby-dev
RUN apt-get -y install gcc
RUN apt-get -y install make
RUN gem install compass
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt-get -y install npm
RUN apt-get -y install git
```

Comment: what like you mean to make an image from this Dockerfile put it on docker hub and `FROM` from that? btw you should consolidate all them lines into a single RUN, else you're making a bunch of intermediate layers [*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223249/multiple-run-vs-single-chained-run-in-dockerfile-which-is-better)

Comment: oh so I should make an image of those first lines and pull that, I get it, I can just have that image locally right? And I will condense those run lines

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share apt-package across Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447375/how-to-share-apt-package-across-docker-containers)

Comment: Docker should cache all of this on its own.  (The first `COPY` or `ADD` directive with changed files would break the layer caching, but you haven't shown any of those at all.)

Answer (score 28):

This will store apt-get packages in the docker cache so they won't need to be re-downloaded. You need to be using buildkit.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3.1
FROM ubuntu

RUN --mount=target=/var/lib/apt/lists,type=cache,sharing=locked \
    --mount=target=/var/cache/apt,type=cache,sharing=locked \
    rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
        ruby ruby-dev gcc
```

See [this documentation](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#run---mounttypecache) for more details.

Comment: Why `rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean` ?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out why. [This](https://vsupalov.com/buildkit-cache-mount-dockerfile/)  site explains it well. For others, essentially Docker deletes these cache files by default so they don't cause bloat in the resulting image. Except when we specify the mount, it automatically excludes them from the image (and we want to keep them in the cache for future builds)